# Dynamic Cell Merging in phpspreadsheet

Tags: codeigniter-3, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

My question is about generating an Excel sheet in codeigniter. The excel sheet sub-headings are not fixed, they are as per data, that's why i am not able to merge cells. Is there any solution for that? [Ex:-Here sub-headings are not fix.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni4nK.png)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("$range1:$range2");
```

Comment: '$range1:$range2' should be "$range1:$range2" because php interprete that single `'` as all string

Answer (score 0):

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("from:to");

exemple: $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A1:F1");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).